# Why is the second for-loop not executing?

Tags: c

The issue in the code below is that the second for-loop does not seem to execute.

I added the `printf("1");` and `printf("h");` statements to test if the loops were executing. The program printed the 1's but not the h's.

Some background info about the program is that I am supposed to allocate a 2D array and store sine waves at different frequencies in each row of the array.

Also the variable `PI` is defined as a macro with value `acos(-1).`

```
short int** Notes = (short int**) calloc(25,sizeof(short int*));
for(int x = 0; x < 25; x++){
    Notes[x] = (short int*) calloc(44100 * (1/3),sizeof(short int));
    }

    for(int x = 0; x < 25; x++){
        float freq;
        switch(x){
            case 0:
                freq = 440.00;
                break;
            case 1:
                freq = 466.16;
                break;
            case 2:
                freq = 493.88;
                break;
            case 3:
                freq = 523.25;
                break;
            case 4:
                freq = 554.37;
                break;
            case 5:
                freq = 587.33;
                break;
            case 6:
                freq = 622.25;
                break;
            case 7:
                freq = 659.25;
                break;
            case 8:
                freq = 698.46;
                break;
            case 9:
                freq = 739.99;
                break;
            case 10:
                freq = 783.99;
                break;
            case 11:
                freq = 830.61;
                break;
            case 12:
                freq = 880.00;
                break;
            case 13:
                freq = 932.33;
                break;
            case 14:
                freq = 987.77;
                break;
            case 15:
                freq = 1046.50;
                break;
            case 16:
                freq = 1109.73;
                break;
            case 17:
                freq = 1174.66;
                break;
            case 18:
                freq = 1244.51;
                break;
            case 19:
                freq = 1318.51;
                break;
            case 20:
                freq = 1396.91;
                break;
            case 21:
                freq = 1479.98;
                break;
            case 22:
                freq = 1567.98;
                break;
            case 23:
                freq = 1661.22;
                break;
            case 24:
                freq = 0.00;
                break;                  
        }
        printf("1");
        for(int y = 0; y < 44100 * (1/3); y++)
        {
            Notes[x][y] = 32700 * sin(2 * PI * freq * (y/44100));
            printf("h");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    for(int y = 0; y < 44100 * (1/3); y++)
```

The substatement never executes because `y < 44100 * (1/3)` is always false.  This is because integer division rounds toward zero, so `(1/3)` and therefore `44100 * (1/3)` are zero.

Assuming you want the value which is one-third of 44100, just write `44100/3`.

Answer (score 3):

Dividing two integers will result in an integer:

```
for(int y = 0; y < 44100 * (1/3); y++)
```

is evaluated as:

```
for(int y = 0; y < 44100 * (0); y++)
```

So you never enter the loop

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int y = 0; y < 44100 * (1/3); y++)
```

Here the testExpression `y < 44100 * (1/3)` always evaluate to `false`.

As `1/3` as both will result in zero as it is integer division and dividing two integers will result integer.

You can use

```
for(int y = 0; y < 44100 * (1.0/3); y++)
```